# checking custom String pattern

Tags: java, regex

I want to check custom pattern for `=SUM(A1:A10)` like that. The place of `A1` and `A10` can change but others are fix. I tried the following code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("SUM[(][A-T][1-20][:][A-T][1-20][)]");
        Matcher m=pattern.matcher("SUM(A9:A1)");
        System.out.println(m.matches());
    }
}
```

But it is not ok. Please help me!

Comment: I think [1-20] as a set is just 1, 2 and 0. Regex deals with characters, not number ranges like that

Comment: If you're doing a *lot* of spreadsheet-style parsing I'd recommend... parsing.

Answer (score 8):

Pattern like `[1-20]` does not match what you seem to believe it does. It does not match numbers between 1 and 20, it matches 1, 2 and 0 instead. To match 1-20, use `([1-9]|1\d|20)` : first part of the alternative matches numbers below 10, second matches range 10-19, third matches 20.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what your regex should look like:

```
SUM\([A-T]([1-9]|1[0-9]|20):[A-T]([1-9]|1[0-9]|20)\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

In a java string:

```
"SUM\\([A-T]([1-9]|1[0-9]|20):[A-T]([1-9]|1[0-9]|20)\\)"
```

Comment: Nice graph @PaulVargas, I did not know [debugex](http://www.debuggex.com), used to [regex101](http://regex101.com)

Comment: Ha ha. No problem. If your expression does not include some constructs that are specific to Java (e.g. `(?<!X)`, it works well.